# android get video thumbnail PATH, not Bitmap

Tags: java, android, eclipse, thumbnails

Is it possible to get the video thumbnail PATH, not Bitmap object itself? I'm aware of method

```
MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.queryMiniThumbnail
```

but since I use my own Bitmap caching mechanism I want to have the path to video thumbnail rather than the Bitmap object itself. This method returns Bitmap object, not path.
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First get the video file URL and then use below query.

Sample Code:

```
private static final String[] VIDEOTHUMBNAIL_TABLE = new String[] {
    Video.Media._ID, // 0
    Video.Media.DATA, // 1 from android.provider.MediaStore.Video
    };

Uri videoUri = MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getContentUri("external");

cursor c = cr.query(videoUri, VIDEOTHUMBNAIL_TABLE, where, 
           new String[] {filepath}, null);

if ((c != null) && c.moveToFirst()) {
  VideoThumbnailPath = c.getString(1);
}
```

VideoThumbnailPath, should have video thumbnail path. Hope it help's.

Comment: What's the value of "where" parameter (3rd parameter on call of c.query)?

Comment: Where String:

Video.Thumbnails.VIDEO_ID  + " In ( select _id from video where _data =?)";

Comment: I can't get this code to work since `c.moveToFirst()` is always false. What exactly is the 'where' string and filepath is the absolute path of the file, right?

Comment: This is so confusing and it is not working for me, anyone able to give a better solution?

Comment: It does not works, is cr : ContentResolver crThumb = App.getContext().getContentResolver(); , and Cursor is : Cursor c = crThumb.query(videoUri, VIDEO_THUMBNAIL_TABLE, " _data =?", new String[] {
                    videoPath
            }, null); ????

Comment: please add full example, `cr, cursor...`

Answer (score 2):

Get Video **thumbnail** path from video_id:

```
public static String getVideoThumbnail(Context context, int videoID) {
        try {
            String[] projection = {
                    MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.DATA,
            };
            ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
            Cursor cursor = cr.query(
                    MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    projection, 
                    MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.VIDEO_ID + "=?", 
                    new String[] { String.valueOf(videoID) }, 
                    null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return null;
    }
```