# How to get the video thumbnail path, and not the bitmap

Tags: android, thumbnails

This question is actually asked and supposedly answered here: [android get video thumbnail PATH, not Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483682/android-get-video-thumbnail-path-not-bitmap).

I've tried several times but can't get it to work. I always get a null returned. Any help on this please?

**Edit:**  The sample code I'm using now:

```
public static String getVideoThumbnailPath(Context context,
        String filePath) {
    String thubmnailPath;
    String where = Video.Thumbnails.VIDEO_ID
            + " In ( select _id from video where _data =?)";
    final String[] VIDEO_THUMBNAIL_TABLE = new String[] { Video.Media._ID, // 0
            Video.Media.DATA, // 1
    };
    Uri videoUri = MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getContentUri("external");

    Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(videoUri,
            VIDEO_THUMBNAIL_TABLE, where, new String[] { filePath }, null);

    if ((c != null) && c.moveToFirst()) {
        thubmnailPath = c.getString(1);
        c.close();
        Log.i(TAG, "thumb path: " + thubmnailPath);
        return thubmnailPath;
    } else {
        c.close();
        Log.i(TAG, "thumb path is null");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: "Any help on this please?" Sure. Any code on this please?

Comment: Are you getting the related permissions for this ?

Comment: Doesn't seem like you need any permissions for this but I do have this permission: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: Did the below solution work for you... it does not seem to work for me?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, you need to know the content uri of the file. If you have the file path, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14456406/1319753) shows you how to get the content uri.

```
public static String[] thumbColumns = { MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.DATA };
public static String[] mediaColumns = { MediaStore.Video.Media._ID };

public static String getThumbnailPathForLocalFile(Activity context,
        Uri fileUri) {

    long fileId = getFileId(context, fileUri);

    MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(context.getContentResolver(),
            fileId, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);

    Cursor thumbCursor = null;
    try {

        thumbCursor = context.managedQuery(
                MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                thumbColumns, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.VIDEO_ID + " = "
                        + fileId, null, null);

        if (thumbCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            String thumbPath = thumbCursor.getString(thumbCursor
                    .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.DATA));

            return thumbPath;
        }

    } finally {
    }

    return null;
}

public static long getFileId(Activity context, Uri fileUri) {

    Cursor cursor = context.managedQuery(fileUri, mediaColumns, null, null,
            null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int columnIndex = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID);
        int id = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);

        return id;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Reference: http://androidcodezs.blogspot.com/2013/10/android-thumbnail-from-video.html**

Comment: `MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail` before  the `Cursor` is the key point, thanks.

Comment: That too I found that works, with that piece of code added before the query it now loads the thumbnail paths.

Comment: thumbCursor.moveToFirst() is always false on Android 5.0.1

Comment: It worked well and i want image to be MICRO_KIND. Can someone please edit the cursor with kind=micro_kind. I tried but failed.

Comment: getThumbnailPathForLocalFile(Activity context,
        Uri fileUri)  
.... FOR which type of file this Uri fileUri parameter is ... (Video .. or ..  ?)

Comment: `getFileId` always returns 0

Comment: does Uri look like `file://storage/emulated/0/video.mp4` or is it something else?